# Gatekeeper Path Randomization for Developer signed DMG?

Tags: macos-sierra, osx-gatekeeper

We are packaging our app for drag and drop installation DMG as following:

```
Application Name/Application.app
Application Name/Readme
Application Name/Examples/...
Application Name/Documentation/...
```

And user is supposed to d&d **Application Name** Folder to **/Applications/**.
Everything is code signed including DMG.

From most information I read this should be enough to prevent app translocation happening, but for some reason it isn't for some of our Sierra users?

The solution for them would be beside d&d folder to **/Applications** is to do another drag & drop (move) **Application.app** somewhere and back to **/Applications/Application Name/** or move only **Application Name/Application.app** overwriting **/Applications/Application Name/Application.app**.

Now the question is why do only some users have this issue, and shouldn't code signing dmg prevent app translocation from happening?

I verified they have selected Allow apps downloaded from Mac App Store and identified developers.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem on my side and had to go get some help via DTS, so I thought I'd repay the favor by replying here:

To avoid translocation, it turns out that not only is the disk image DMG supposed to be signed, but the file format for the image needs to be very specific: `UDRO`.

You can see more information about `UDRO` when you look at the man page for the [`hdiutil` command line tool](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/hdiutil.1.html).

Comment: The format I'm using is `UDZO` I tried setting `UDRO` and the only thing changed was the file size increased, but it didn't help with GPRP, the app was still translocated after moving folder containing it.

Comment: So if you `cd` into the disk image in the Terminal and type in "`hdiutil info`", do you see `UDRO` as the format?

Comment: I have shell script that first creates `-fs HFS+ -format UDRW` image mounts it and prepares everything in it, and than I do `hdiutil convert temp.dmg -format UDZO -o final.dmg` after that I codesing dmg I tried using `-format UDRO` instead and it didn't help. hdiutil imageinfo gives me `Format: UDRO`